# How do I combining two or more images in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, combinations

I need to combine several images **(of different textures)** together. I have tried the following code:

```
% Read 4d data
I1 = importdata('Img1.tif');    
I2 = importdata('Img2.tif');

% Extract a slice of the data
extractImg1 = I1(:,:,1); 
extractImg2 = I2(:,:,1); 

% compute image size
[ny1, nx1] = size(extractA1);
[ny2, nx2] = size(extractA2);

P1 = extractImg1 (round(ny1/2)-120:round(ny1/2)+120, round(nx1/2)-120:round(nx1/2)+120);
figure, imshow(P1); title('Img1');
P2 = extractImg2 (round(ny2/2)-120:round(ny2/2)+120, round(nx2/2)-120:round(nx2/2)+120);
figure, imshow(P2); title('Img2');
```

Please, what should I do next?

Secondly, the combined image will be needed for laser printing. The images do not have exactly the same pixel dimensions thus; I was told that it would not make sense to combine them, as this might slightly reduce accuracy.

Nonetheless, I still have a feeling that combining the images wouldn’t be wrong considering that they all have the same resolutions.

I need advice as to whether I should go ahead with the combination. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: They don't have the same pixel sizes but they have the same resolution? Makes not sense. Resolution is given by the size of a pixel.

Comment: What do you mean by "combine" them?  Do you want them overlaid, stacked next to each other, something else? Be more specific.

Comment: @Phil Goddard: i would need them side by side. Thank you!

Comment: @Cris Luengo: by the resolution, i meant the physical measurement of each pixel in the image. For instance: `img1` has pixel dimensions of `457x456`, but physical dimensions of `322 micron x 322 micron`; `img2` is `480 x 481 pixels`, and measures `338 x 339 microns`. The resolutions for each should be: `322/457 = 0.705 micron/pixel`, and `338/480 = 0.705 micron/pixel`, respectively. Please correct me if i am wrong. Thank you!

Comment: @User1772 That is exactly right. What do you mean by “pixel sizes” then? The size in pixels? I misunderstood that as the size of the pixels. :)

Comment: Oh i see! i actually meant the dimensions in pixels. i have edited that just now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extracted two equal-sized regions from the two images. If you want to put those side-by-side in the same image, use [`cat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html), or equivalently, use the square brackets `[]`:

```
next_to_each_other = [P1,P2];
on_top_of_each_other = [P1;P2];
```

But note that you can put these things together even if they don't have the same sizes. For example, if `I1` is `N`x`M` pixels, and `I2` is `N`x`K` (with `N` the vertical size as customary in MATLAB) then you can still do `[I1,I2]` because the vertical size matches.

If nether the vertical nor horizontal sizes match, you can pad one with zeros (or whatever value is appropriate) using [`padarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html) before putting them together:

```
ny1 = size(I1,1);
ny2 = size(I2,1);
if ny1<ny2
   I1 = padarray(I1,[ny2-ny1,0,0],0,'post'); % The 0 is the value to pad
elseif ny2<ny1
   I2 = padarray(I2,[ny1-ny2,0,0],0,'post'); % The 0 is the value to pad
end
out = [I1,I2];
```

`padarray` also allows replicating the data in the matrix instead of padding with zeros. Read the documentation to find what is appropriate. `padarray` requires the Image Processing Toolbox. If you don't have it, you can replicate its functionality by creating an array with zeros of the appropriate size using the `zeros` function, and adding it to the image using something like `[I1;zeros(ny2-ny1,size(I1,2),size(I1,3)]`.

Comment: very nice and detailed explanation. Thank you very much. Do you please have any advice regarding the 2nd part of my question?

Comment: @User1772 I don’t see why not to combine them, but I guess it depends on what you want to accomplish. By padding, rather than rescaling, you are keeping the resolution unchanged, so there should be no issues with accuracy.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much.